# Create pads to solder in

Tags: soldering, kicad

I am designing a circuit in Kicad.

[image]

The emitter of the BJT should become connected to a speaker.
The other end of the speaker should be connected to GND.

My plan is to have the speaker NOT soldered on the board. It should be external of the board and connected to the board with wires.

I want to create small spaces on the board filled with solder, in order to have the wires soldered there.

How do I do this in Kicad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a schematic symbol representing contact pads, with a footprint that includes physical pads on the board. This can be two one-pin connectors, or a single two-pin connector.

In KiCAD 7 (and likely older versions), there's a built-in collection of footprints called `Connector_Wire` containing a bunch of pads for soldering wire. Some of them even include secondary holes for strain relief, for example `SolderWire-0.75sqmm_1x01_D1.25mm_OD3.5mm_Relief` for a pair of 0.75 sq mm wires:

[image]

Of course, you'll want to pick one with a diameter that works well with the wire you want to solder.

If you don't like any of the footprints in that footprint library, you should be able to use any footprint with one or two numbered pads (depending on whether you used two 1x connectors or one 2x connector in the schematic).

> I want to create small spaces on the board filled with solder, in order to have the wires soldered there.

You likely don't want those spots pre-filled with solder. The footprint I showed above includes plated through-holes; you can insert a wire into the hole and solder it in place; the solder will wick into the inner surface of the hole (which is plated with copper and/or your board finish) and provide a decent connection (but probably not strong enough to pull on directly without strain relief).

Comment: To connect wires to a PCB some times I choose a 2 pin connector.  Do not populate the connector but just use the two holes for wires.

Comment: Thanks for the footprint tip, but what is the symbol that i choose in the schematic editor?

Comment: @user1584421 Any two-pin footprint (or two one-pin footprints), probably. one of the generic Connector entries. I don't have the name off the top of my head (not near my personal laptop at the moment)

Comment: But why create two pin footprints? I am considering using a Conn_01X01_Male - which is a connector for a single pin header. Why it has to be two? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: @user1584421 If you want Conn_01X01_Male, which contains one pin for one signal, you need two of them - one for SPEAKER_IN, and one for SPEAKER_OUT. You then get to place two footprints in whatever spot is convenient. On the other hand, if you want to use Conn_01X02_Male or similar, it has two pins and can connect both SPEAKER_IN and SPEAKER_OUT, and you place a single two-pad footprint on your PCB.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helpful advice, and still your solution offered freedom to choose whatever I see fit.